# yarn install node-sass problem on macOS 12.4

Tags: reactjs, macos, node-sass

I cannot install all dependencies for my React project. I am using macOS 12.4, node version is v17.6.0, npm version is 8.5.1 and finally yarn version is 1.22.19.
I am getting this error when I type 'yarn' in terminal:

```
    2 warnings generated.
  rm -f Release/sass.a && ./gyp-mac-tool filter-libtool libtool  -static -o Release/sass.a Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/backtrace.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/base64vlq.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/bind.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cencode.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/check_nesting.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/color_maps.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/constants.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/context.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cssize.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/emitter.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/environment.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/error_handling.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/eval.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/expand.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/extend.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/file.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/functions.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/inspect.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/json.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/lexer.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/listize.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/memory/SharedPtr.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/node.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/operators.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/output.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/parser.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/plugins.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/position.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/prelexer.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/remove_placeholders.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass2scss.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_context.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_functions.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_util.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_values.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/source_map.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/subset_map.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/to_c.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/to_value.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/units.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/utf8_string.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/util.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/values.o
env: python: No such file or directory
make: *** [Release/sass.a] Error 127
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/macbook/VSCode/business-front/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/macbook/.nvm/versions/node/v17.6.0/bin/node" "/Users/macbook/VSCode/business-front/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/macbook/VSCode/business-front/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v17.6.0
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "business",
  "version": "0.1.5",
  "description": "Front-end service fo business",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/egaranti/business-front.git"
  },
  "author": "eGaranti Devs",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/business/business-front/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "www.google.com",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "on-finished": "~2.3.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-range": "^1.8.13",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-select-search": "^3.0.9",
    "react-switch": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "validator": "^13.7.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "prod": "serve -l 4001 -s build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "prettier --config .prettierrc \"src/**/*.js\" --write"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^2.5.0",
    "serve": "^13.0.2"
  }
}
```

I tried to solve this problem by installing python3 and Xcode, but it didn't work for me. I didn't any problem for my Windows machine. How can I solve this or Anyone solve this?

**SOLVED:** I installed pyenv and also install python 2.7.18 using pyenv, then restart the terminal. It works!

Comment: did you try to change the "node-sass" version in your package.json (for exemple  "node-sass": "4.10.0")

Comment: Thx for your comment, but it didn't work.

Comment: check this out it might help you resolve your issue :) https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/error+node+sass+package+json+install